# default.png does not work

Tags: objective-c, ios, default.png

My application's opening screen default.png works on similator but not on ipad device. I tried these: Default.png, default.png but no change. Still does not work. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the app from the device, cleaning the build and trying again.  I've had this before where it used (or didn't use) a cached image.  Deleting from the device is the important part!

Comment: I tried that, I deleted app from device and again running but it not works :S

Comment: And you cleaned the build in Xcode too? (Product menu -> Clean)?

Answer (score 0):

name it to Default.png,default.png not gonna work for device...delete the existing one from physical path then add it again...should be always Default.png.if you are using XCode 4+ go to Project Target->Summary->Launch Image->Select the image from there...Clean target before that...

Answer (score 0):

For setting launch image for iPad, you must set it with orientation. Just try to set

```
 Default-Portrait.png
```

For more [info](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=840/) and [Apple HUG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Answer (score 0):

For iPad, you may want to take into account that different rotations may need different splash screens.

I found this to be pretty useful: http://iosdevelopertips.com/ipad/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images.html